# Check Airpods battery percentage on Linux

Tags: linux, arch-linux, bluetooth, blueman

Recently I connected my Airpods to my PC which contain arch linux. So I wish to know how can I check my Airpod's battery percentage on my PC. Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This](https://github.com/delphiki/AirStatus) seems like it would do the trick. Since you're on Arch, you might want to use the [AUR version](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/airstatus-git).

Comment: Hi! I managed to install this package. When I run python file I get this error:
https://jpst.it/2Wluu

Comment: @ThinuraDinujaya I see you submitted [an issue](https://github.com/delphiki/AirStatus/issues/13) to the upstream. I don't have airpods, so I can't test the software myself. Hope the issue gets addressed.

Comment: It's Okay. Anyway thanks for help mate!